# Dropzone.js event after drop end and before uploading

Tags: javascript, events, dropzone.js

I'm looking for a `dropzone.js` event that raises after the drop end and just before the uploading.

What I need is to have access to all the information about the dropped files at once, not file by file thus `addedfile` event is not an option.

I thought that the `dragend` event was the appropriate, but it's not triggered when I drop the files in my dropzone.

The code snippet that I'm using looks like as follows:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
    autoProcessQueue : false,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files or click here to upload a new DICOM series ...",
    init : function() {

        myDropzone = this;

        //Restore initial message when queue has been completed
        this.on("dragend", function(file) {
            console.log("ondragend");            
        });

    }
```

};

Am I missing something? Is there any other event in `dropzone.js` for this purpose?

Answer (score 8):

There is an [event](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events) called [`addedfiles`](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-addedfiles), which will fire on both "drag-and-drop" and manual file selection.

```
this.on("addedfiles", function(files) {
     console.log(files.length + ' files added');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a  callback for the drop event, you should use 'drop'. In the event take a look at the 'files' Array. But be aware, that this event isn't fired if the user clicks at the dropzone and selects a file from there.

```
Dropzone.options.MyDropzone = {
    autoProcessQueue : false,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files or click here to upload a new DICOM series ...",
    init : function() {

        myDropzone = this;

        //Restore initial message when queue has been completed
        this.on("drop", function(event) {
            console.log(myDropzone.files);            
        });

    }
};
```

See this fiddle for example: [jsfiddle.net/qqkbzv5a/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/qqkbzv5a/2/)

Comment: In my case it only works when drag and droping not when choose in file dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have use the `selectedfiles` event, which responses either the drop and the click action at the dropzone.

```
 this.on("selectedfiles", function(listFiles) {
            cont_files = listFiles.length;
        });
```