# Update UI right after selecting files in Dropzone JS

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, dropzone.js

I'm uploading files using Dropzone JS.
Within the accept event, for each selected file I'm checking if the file is allowed by the system rules.

But, when I select more than 1000 files, it takes a while until the Dropzone is presenting the thumbnail in the UI.

My solution is to load a modal which says "Please wait, processing the files".

Therefore, I need some event which happens before the 'accept' or 'filesadded', etc.. events.
The 'drop' event was close for the purpose but with two problems:

1. I need it also for the Dropzone click scenario on not only for drag and drop.
2. The modal was not loaded fast enough and wasn't fully presented to the user.

Please advise?

I hope the issue is clear.
Thanks ahead.

Comment: You could look into the API: https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events
And find the listener you need for the event

Comment: Yes, I need better than that. I did mention that  'accept', 'filesadded' and 'drop' did not work.

Comment: Does the answer here be of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392376/dropzone-js-event-after-drop-end-and-before-uploading

Comment: No :( still did not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, worked it out :)
I used the on click event on the hidden file input and dropzone drop event to update the UI (upload a modal), and used the accept dropzone event to hide the modal.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 $("#inputGroupFile01").dropzone({
        drop: function ()
        {
            $('#loadingFilesModel').modal('show');
        }, 
        accept: function (file, done) {
                clearTimeout(fileProcessTO);
                fileProcessTO = setTimeout(function () {
                    $("input[type=file]").on('click', function () {
                        $('#loadingFilesModel').modal('show');
                    });
                    $('#loadingFilesModel').modal('hide');
                }, 300);
 });

$("input[type=file]").on('click', function () {
    $('#loadingFilesModel').modal('show');
});

$('#loadingFilesModel').on('focus', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($('#loadingFilesModel').is(":focus"))
            $('#loadingFilesModel').modal('hide');
    }, 500)
});
```